# Python WebDriver FireFox Questions

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to work on a google scraper with firefox in python and I've ran into some issues when trying to execute

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchFrameException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox') 
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

.....

br = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")
```

And this is my terminal output when I try to run the script:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firefox-google.py", line 22, in 
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/home/dave/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 142, in init
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/dave/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/home/dave/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/subprocess.py", line 586, in init
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/dave/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/subprocess.py", line 555, in init
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/dave/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/subprocess.py", line 1313, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error`

"OSError: [Errno 8]" My shebang doesnt seem to be the issue as ive tried #!/usr/bin/env python2, and #! /usr/bin/python. My binary path for firefox is correct and I included geckodriver to my path. Not sure what the issue is (kind of a noob) any help is appreciated, can post the full source if needed.

Comment: Iv always had problems with using selenium with firefox so I just use chrome.

Comment: it seems that you have a corrupt firefox driver or a corrupt firefox binary

Comment: What version of Firefox and geckodriver are you using? Did you download the correct geckodriver for your OS?

Comment: Yes I had the correct version of Firefox and geckodriver, not sure what the issue was but switching to chrome like thesonyman101 said worked